# How to split the ByteArray by reading from the file in C++?

Tags: java, c++, c, arrays

I have written a Java program to write the `ByteArray` in to a file. And that resulting `ByteArray` is a resulting of these three ByteArrays-

- First **2 bytes** is my `schemaId` which I have represented it using short data type.
- Then next **8 Bytes** is my `Last Modified Date` which I have represented it using long data type.
- And remaining bytes can be of variable size which is my actual value for my attributes..

So I have a file now in which first line contains resulting ByteArray which will have all the above bytes as I mentioned above.. Now I need to read that file from C++ program and read the first line which will contain the ByteArray and then split that resulting ByteArray accordingly as I mentioned above such that I am able to extract my `schemaId`, `Last Modified Date` and my actual attribute value from it.

I have done all my coding always in Java and I am new to C++... I am able to write a program in C++ to read the file but not sure how should I read that ByteArray in such a way such that I am able to split it as I mentioned above..

Below is my C++ program which is reading the file and printing it out on the console..

```
int main () {
    string line;

    //the variable of type ifstream:
    ifstream myfile ("bytearrayfile");

    //check to see if the file is opened:
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        //while there are still lines in the
        //file, keep reading:
        while (! myfile.eof() )
        {
            //place the line from myfile into the
            //line variable:
            getline (myfile,line);

            //display the line we gathered:
            // and here split the byte array accordingly..
            cout << line << endl;
        }

        //close the stream:
        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me with that? Thanks.

**Update**

Below is my java code which will write resulting ByteArray into a file and the same file now I need to read it back from c++..

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String os = "whatever os is";
    byte[] avroBinaryValue = os.getBytes();

    long lastModifiedDate = 1379811105109L;
    short schemaId = 32767;

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOsTest = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream outTest = new DataOutputStream(byteOsTest);
    outTest.writeShort(schemaId);
    outTest.writeLong(lastModifiedDate);
    outTest.writeInt(avroBinaryValue.length);
    outTest.write(avroBinaryValue);

    byte[] allWrittenBytesTest = byteOsTest.toByteArray();

    DataInputStream inTest = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(allWrittenBytesTest));

    short schemaIdTest = inTest.readShort();

    long lastModifiedDateTest = inTest.readLong();

    int sizeAvroTest = inTest.readInt();
    byte[] avroBinaryValue1 = new byte[sizeAvroTest];
    inTest.read(avroBinaryValue1, 0, sizeAvroTest);


    System.out.println(schemaIdTest);
    System.out.println(lastModifiedDateTest);
    System.out.println(new String(avroBinaryValue1));

    writeFile(allWrittenBytesTest);
}

    /**
 * Write the file in Java
 * @param byteArray
 */
public static void writeFile(byte[] byteArray) {

    try{
        File file = new File("bytearrayfile");

        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
        IOUtils.write(byteArray, output);           
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your descriptions seems to suggest that you are writing binary data, and therefore it is very likely that this C++ program won't print anything (because of early 0 bytes,) or won't print anything useful. What are you seeing and what do you expect to see?

Comment: Just as a tip, you need to know the difference between **binary** and **textual** data and how to read/parse them.

Comment: @yzt: Yes..This C++ program is not complete as I haven't added any logic to split the ByteArray. Or it might be another way to read the file which contains ByteArray in the line.. I am a Java developer mostly so not that much familiar with C++... Right now the above c++ program will just print out each line...

Comment: From a Java perspective, this doesn't make sense.  1) There is no standard `ByteArray` type in Java.  2) If you are talking about a `byte[]` then you need to say *how* you are writing it in Java.  There are lots of ways to do it that will result in *different* file formats.

Comment: @StephenC: I updated my question with my Java code which will write resulting ByteArray into a file.. Let me know if it makes sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you want to use `std::getline` to read this data. Your file isn't written as text data on a line-by-line basis - it basically has a binary format.

You can use the `read` method of `std::ifstream` to read arbitrary chunks of data from an input stream. You probably want to open the file in binary mode:

```
std::ifstream myfile("bytearrayfile", std::ios::binary);
```

Fundamentally the method you would use to read each record from the file is:

```
uint16_t schemaId;
uint64_t lastModifiedDate;
uint32_t binaryLength;

myfile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&schemaId), sizeof(schemaId));
myfile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&lastModifiedDate), sizeof(lastModifiedDate));
myfile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&binaryLength), sizeof(binaryLength));
```

This will read the three static members of your data structure from the file. Because your data is variable size, you probably need to allocate a buffer to read it into, for example:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> binaryBuf(new char[binaryLength]);
myfile.read(binaryBuf.get(), binaryLength);
```

The above are **examples** only to illustrate how you would approach this in C++. You will need to be aware of the following things:

- There's no error checking in the above examples. You'll need to check that the calls to [`ifstream::read`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/) are successful and return the correct amount of data.
- [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) may be an issue, depending on the the platform the data originates from and is being read on.
- Interpreting the `lastModifiedDate` field may require you to write a function to convert it from whatever format Java uses (I have no idea about Java).

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonathan.. Appreciated your help on this.. Is it possible for you to put these pieces of code together for me with my c++ example? As I am a Java developer, it will take atleast couple of hours to figure out where to add those lines of code... And regarding `lastModifiedDate`, I would like to read as the way it is currently in Java, which is - `1379811105109`..